# How to use the parameter of g in command of wget

Tags: wget

I find someone use "wget -g 'a ip' -l /tmp/l -r /1 "。 I use the command of "man wget" in linux.But i don't find the parameter of g. who can tell me the use of g?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an FTP parameter used to turn on file globbing.